# Update first, if not then insert (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like `insert on duplicate key update` but reverse i.e. first it should try to update, and if it doesn't exist, then it should insert.

Why? Because I am running a large number of these queries and most of them are actually update queries and not insert queries. So if I use `insert on duplicate key update` it takes longer because it's actually 2 queries. So if I can somehow do the reverse it will be ideal.

Any suggestions? If it's not possible, then how do I make this more efficient. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with MySQL command line "Load data file". But it no SQL query.

13.2.6 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an issue.

Look at what IODKU has to do -- whether it tries `INSERT` first or second.

1. Locate the row(s) based on the unique key(s) -- If things are not completely cached, then this is the slowest step.
2. No row -- `INSERT`.  Note that the block(s) needed are sitting in the buffer_pool.
3. Row exists -- `UPDATE`.

Furthermore, the `INSERT` must be tested because it can succeed or fail.  The `UPDATE` does not have success/fail.